# setting python Decimal when defining precision yields inexact Decimal

Tags: python, unit-testing, floating-point, decimal

Why can't I explicitly declare an exact `Decimal` object within the precision I configured it to?

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 5

num = Decimal(0.1234)
print num
```

Expected Output:

```
0.1234
```

Actual Output:

```
0.12339999999999999580335696691690827719867229461669921875
```

Ultimately, I'm writing unit tests that compare Decimal objects that are failing since the expected value is inexact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.1234` is converted to standard IEEE-754 radix-2 floating point number first, then that approximation is converted to Decimal. Just leave it as a string.

```
>>> Decimal(0.1234)
Decimal('0.12339999999999999580335696691690827719867229461669921875')
>>> Decimal('0.1234')
Decimal('0.1234')
```