# why does sum of decimals still have floating point errors?

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, decimal

Im using the decimals module to try to avoid floating point errors. From the decimal module's documentary it says:

> Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like
>   1.1 and 2.2 do not have exact representations in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect 1.1 + 2.2 to display as
>   3.3000000000000003 as it does with binary floating point.

But when I try sum with decimals, I still get those floating point errors.

```
decimal.Decimal(4.04)+decimal.Decimal(4.04)
>>Decimal('8.080000000000000071054273576')
```

Why is this?

Comment: This is a common mistake; there should be plenty of duplicates around, but I'm having trouble finding them. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25829853/270986

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting strings around your float literals, like so:

```
decimal.Decimal('4.04')+decimal.Decimal('4.04')
```

In the code in your question, the raw binary (base 2) `"float"` type is passed to `Decimal`. When you use strings to represent the number `4.04` for example, `Decimal` represents `'4.04'` precisely in base 10.